# For rows in a tibble, how to count the greatest number of TRUE values between FALSE values?

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have a tibble in the form

```
    passengerId   FlightChain
1   1             c("TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE")
2   2             TRUE
3   3             c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

and I'm trying to get the highest count of "TRUES" between "FALSE"s as it's own column.

so in this case:

```
   passengerId   fullFlightChain
1   1             3
2   2             1
3   3             2
```

I first had the tibble in format:

```
   passengerId flightTo
         <int> <lgl>     
 1           1 TRUE      
 2           1 TRUE      
 3           1 FALSE      
 4           1 TRUE      
 5           1 TRUE      
 6           1 TRUE      
 7           1 FALSE      
 8           1 TRUE      
 9           2 TRUE      
10           3 TRUE
11           3 FALSE
```

etc....

so if it would actually be better to work from (grouping by passengerId) there I'm all ears. From what I've heard rle() is a function that might work, but I can't get it to work properly.

Thanks

Edit: now with code

```
df_q3 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(passengerId) %>%
  arrange(passengerId) %>%
  mutate(flightToUK = if_else(to == "uk", FALSE, TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(fullFlightChain = paste(flightToUK, collapse = "-")) %>%
  mutate(fullFlightChainSplit = str_split(fullFlightChain, "-")) %>%
  map(fullFlightChainSplit,rle(fullFlightChainSplit))) %>%
  print()
```

Where the last line is where I'm trying to make the count as seen in the first table

Comment: your first and third tibbles do not match!

Comment: Maybe you have given a part of the actual tibble you had initially

Comment: Vitali they're not direct output from the code, merely example outputs I wrote freehand for this, since the files in question are significantly longer!

Comment: Now I understand, thanks. Please check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking as an input your initial `tibble` format, *i.e.*:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read_table2("passengerId flightTo
1 TRUE      
1 TRUE      
1 FALSE      
1 TRUE      
1 TRUE      
1 TRUE      
1 FALSE      
1 TRUE      
2 TRUE      
3 TRUE
3 FALSE")
```

This is the best solution to your problem:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(passengerId) %>% 
  transmute(fullFlightChain = with(rle(flightTo), max(lengths[values]))
) %>% 
  unique(.)
```

Output:

```
> df1
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   passengerId [3]
  passengerId fullFlightChain
        <dbl>           <int>
1           1               3
2           2               1
3           3               1
```

*EDIT*: Adding the missing rows to your initial `tibble` and producing the output:

```
df <- read_table2("passengerId flightTo
1 TRUE      
1 TRUE      
1 FALSE      
1 TRUE      
1 TRUE      
1 TRUE      
1 FALSE      
1 TRUE      
2 TRUE      
3 TRUE
3 FALSE
3 TRUE
3 TRUE
3 FALSE")

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(passengerId) %>% 
  transmute(fullFlightChain = with(rle(flightTo), max(lengths[values]))
) %>% 
  unique(.)
```

Output:

```
> df1
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   passengerId [3]
  passengerId fullFlightChain
        <dbl>           <int>
1           1               3
2           2               1
3           3               2
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked superbly. I was just wondering, exactly why this method using with() works, and the exact meaning of  max(lengths[values]). There does also seem to be some sort of error warning: In max(lengths[values]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf, that it returns for each line, but the output values seem correct, so this seems inconsequential

Comment: Type `?with`, there are some good examples of how to use `with`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `rle` function which encodes a vector by values and lengths would allow you to examine the max length that had a TRUE value. Something along these lines although untested in the absence of example built in code.

```
 RLE <- rle(flightTo)
 mxT <- max(  RLE$lengths[RLE$values == TRUE] )
```

Or for multiple items in a list:

```
 lapply( list_name, function(line){ 
                          RLE <- rle(flightTo)
                          mxT <- max(  RLE$lengths[RLE$values == TRUE] ) }
```

Comment: and would that work in the pipe? I think that's what's causing most of the issues frankly. As in, something like that would likely work as I've seen in other answers, but I'm struggling to get it to do that operation for each row in the column

Comment: Post an example built with code. When I search SO for "[r] tibble rle" I get over 100 results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is both a reproducible example and the solution based on rle

```
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(4242)
tbl <- tibble(passID = sample(1:3, 20, replace = TRUE),
              flightTO = sample(c(T, F), 20, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(passID)


rle(tbl$flightTO)

tbl %>%
  group_by(passID) %>%
  do({tmp <- with(rle(.$flightTO==TRUE), lengths[values])
  data.frame(passID= .$passID, Max=if(length(tmp)==0) 0 
             else max(tmp)) }) %>% 
  slice(1L)
```

**UPDATE**
simply use my code to create a temporary object which you will use to join to the main summarised object, keeping the critical "Max" column which summarises the maximum run length by passID. "tbl" is your "df1"

```
temp_obj <- tbl %>%
  group_by(passID) %>%
  do({tmp <- with(rle(.$flightTO==TRUE), lengths[values])
  data.frame(passID= .$passID, Max=if(length(tmp)==0) 0 
             else max(tmp)) }) %>% 
  slice(1L)

your_new_obj_where_you_summarise_other_stuff <- tbl %>%
  group_by(passID) %>%
  summarise(..other summary statistics you need..) %>%
  inner_join(temp_obj, by = "passID")
```

Comment: I'll see what I can do with this, though I've also added some of my personal code to the question now, in case you see any changes that might be needed. and thanks, I'm still relatively new to R

Comment: you will need to use my code to create a separate object. join back the "Max" column from that object with your new summarised object by "passID".

Comment: see my update which shows the join..
and plz accept answer if this is the solution you sought. thx

Comment: You answer did work, however I'm going to use the solution by Vitali about as it runs faster. I appreciate the effort though, I'd been stuck on that one for a while and you two helped really me out